# Is the name of a permission in android manifest not case-sensitive?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I am working on a software that analyzes android apps. While reviewing the results I found that several devs had mixed case in their permissions e.g. `ACCESS_iNTERNET`

Is the permission handling not case-senstive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are case sensitive. Not documented, but I tried it.

Anyway, `android.permission.ACCESS_INTERNET` or `android.permission.ACCESS_iNTERNET` won't change anything because the correct name is `android.permission.INTERNET`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET