# Read and write UserDictionary permission denial

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-contentresolver

A simple app that searches a word from the user input in the `UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI` table. I am using BlueStacks emulator. 
Error LOG states that there is no `android.permission.READ_USER_DICTIONARY` or `android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY` declared in my `AndroidManifest`. But I have both declared:

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.READ_USER_DICTIONARY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY"/>
```

How to resolve this?

Error log:

```
01-26 21:14:03.361    5988-6040/system_process E/InputDispatcher﹕ Motion event has invalid pointer count 0; value must be between 1 and 16.
01-26 21:14:03.461    5988-6040/system_process E/InputDispatcher﹕ Motion event has invalid pointer count 0; value must be between 1 and 16.
01-26 21:14:03.461    9025-9025/com.example.contentresolver2 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.example.contentresolver2
01-26 21:14:03.471    9025-9025/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.contentresolver2, PID: 9025
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.userdictionary.UserDictionaryProvider from ProcessRecord{4b18dc58 9025:com.example.contentresolver2/u0a67} (pid=9025, uid=10067) requires android.permission.READ_USER_DICTIONARY or android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
            at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:2848)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4419)
            at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2213)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1425)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:445)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:404)
            at com.example.contentresolver2.MainActivity.performSearch(MainActivity.java:64)
            at com.example.contentresolver2.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:29)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4443)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18433)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.contentresolver2"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.READ_USER_DICTIONARY"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY"/>

    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.contentresolver2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.UserDictionary;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Cursor mCursor;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "LOG_TAG";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        (findViewById(R.id.btnSearch)).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnSearch:
                performSearch();
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Read the word from the input and search in Android UserDictionary.Words table
     */
    private void performSearch() {

        // Select columns for projection
        String[] projection = {
                UserDictionary.Words._ID,
                UserDictionary.Words.WORD,
                UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE
        };
        String selectionClause = null;
        String[] selectionArgs = {""}; // only one element array
        String sortOrder = null;

        // Read user input
        String userInput = ((EditText) (findViewById(R.id.etSearchString))).getText().toString();

        // Decide what kind of request to perform
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userInput)) {
            // Setting the selection clause to null will return all words
            selectionClause = null;
            selectionArgs[0] = "";
        } else {
            // Or setting the selection clause to find the word from the input
            selectionClause = UserDictionary.Words.WORD + "= ?";
            selectionArgs[0] = userInput;
        }

        // Perform query
        mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                selectionClause,
                selectionArgs,
                sortOrder
        );

        // Some providers return null if an error occurs, others throw an exception
        if (null == mCursor) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "MainActivity > performSearch(): mCursor is null");

            // If the Cursor is empty, the provider found no matches
        } else if (mCursor.getCount() < 1) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "MainActivity > performSearch(): mCursor mCursor is empty");

            // Results:
        } else {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
            String resultString = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(UserDictionary.Words.WORD));
            ((TextView) (findViewById(R.id.tvResultString))).setText(resultString);
        }
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <TextView
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Search in UserDictionary"
            />
    <EditText
            android:hint="Input a word to search in UserDictionary"
            android:id="@+id/etSearchString"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
            android:text="Search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvResultString"
            android:text="___"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFF00"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562996/is-the-name-of-a-permission-in-android-manifest-not-case-sensitive Looks like permissions are case sensitive.